Is it possible to change the message of the char limit?
Is there any possibility to change the message in the character limitation in a textInput type of component?
To be more specific, I'm referring to this message:

If you limit the characters, it shows 1 above or 1 below the number you use, for example:
"input-type": "number",
"min-chars": 8,
"max-chars": 8,

it will say:
if you put less than 8: "this answer needs to have more than 7"
if you put more than 8: "this answer needs to have less than 9"
and in the Meta documentation, it never says that there's an option to specify a number (instead of selecting the upper and lower limit).
This is rather confusing for the majority of the users.
I didn't find any way to solve this.

It is not currently possible to control the text for this error message.

This is not supported, but you may want to put your desired message inside helper-text.
eg.
"helper-text": "Please enter exactly 8 digits"

This is only visible when the field is empty and only if the field hasn't been touched yet, but combined with the error text it may make the interface less confusing for your users.

And/or if you wanted you could also indicate the desired count in the label property (any way that you want) so that it's still clear even after the field has been touched:


I think you are right that it ought to support specifying an exact number of characters though, so you may also want to submit this as a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/
Or post in their community forums: https://developers.facebook.com/community/
